# Creating a 4d matrix from a 3d array and 2d arrray

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

I was trying to create what I thought was a simple visualization for hedge fund economics, but I am struggling with the dimensions.

I have 4 arrays that represent returns, management fees, capital, and perf_fee:

```
pct_fee = np.linspace(0.5,1.5,num = 3).reshape(3,)
capital = np.linspace(50, 150.0, num = len(pct_fee))
perf_fee = np.linspace(10.0, 20.0, num = len(pct_fee))
returns = np.linspace(5.0, 15.0, num = len(pct_fee))
```

I then multiplied the arrays together:

```
fee_income = np.multiply.outer((pct_fee/100), capital).transpose() #3x3 matrix
perf = np.multiply.outer((returns/100), capital).transpose() #3X3 matrix
perf_fees = np.multiply.outer((perf_fee/100), perf).transpose() #3X3X3 matrix
```

This leaves me with `fee_income` which is a matrix of mgmt fees and capital and `perf_fees` which is a matrix of returns, capital, and performance fees.

What is the best way to combine the two arrays so that I have a matrix of `total_fees` comprised of varying capital, varying performance fees, varying returns, and varying mgmt fees?

I tried to add a dimension to `fee_income` and use `np.dstack`, but I keep getting the error `ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly`.

Frankly, I am not sure if that is even the best way to approach the problem; I believe I am expecting a 4d array.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you give the formula you want to compute? Is it `fee_income` which is a function of the 4 variables `pct_fee`, `capital`, `perf_fee` and `returns`? If it is the case I will use [meshgrid](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html)

Comment: That would have been good for me to add! 'total fees' = ('capital'*'returns'*'perf_fee') + ('capital'*'pct_fee').  Sorry for that omission.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what your are looking for:

```
import numpy as np

pct_fee = np.linspace(0.5, 1.5, num=3)
capital = np.linspace(50, 150.0, num=len(pct_fee))
perf_fee = np.linspace(10.0, 20.0, num=len(pct_fee))
returns = np.linspace(5.0, 15.0, num=len(pct_fee))

pct_fee_grid, capital_grid, perf_fee_grid, returns_grid = np.meshgrid(pct_fee, capital, perf_fee, returns)

total_fees_grid = capital_grid*returns_grid*perf_fee_grid + capital_grid*pct_fee_grid 

print(total_fees_grid.shape)  # (3, 3, 3, 3)
```

Comment: That's great thanks. I wasn't familiar with meshgrid.